# Edit a file via bash script

Tags: linux, centos, bash

I am a beginner in bash scripting.I want to create  a bash script to install install and configure stuffs on my linux box in an automated way.

Suppose i want to edit

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

by the bash script

What i want to do is as follows

1. Open file /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
2. Find [epel] section
3. Add a line priority=10 just after line enabled=1 in the epel section

For the first part i added

```
yum install nano
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

My Question is how to do the 2 and 3rd part with bash script using nano (if possible , in case not possible then show me with sed)

Also at some points i will have to modify variables in files 
For e.g

1. enable = 0 to enable = 1
2. Testing = "1" to Testing = "0"
3. Add text in a line . functions = to function = "text1","text2"
4. Add some text to a file and save it(with nano)

I know its demanding but i need to create this for a friend who is noob at server management.Unfortunately i don't have time to study bash scripting from start as my exams as near.I will use your examples to write the script.

---

Guys thanks for all the replies 
I have successfully done most of the bash script

However i have another problem 
Lets suppose i want to modify nginx.conf using sed
We will  deal with worker_processes
Now i want use sed to do the following
1.Find the **FIRST occurrence** of  `worker_processes`  in that conf and replace text with `worker_processes 4;`

Special Note Here: This is just an example. It may happen that the conf contain 
worker_processes 1; . This is hard part . I want a sed command that find the **FIRST wHOLE match case** of the word **worker_processes** , delete line of text where the word is found and and paste  `worker_processes 4;` there and then save file.
This is the most reliable method i though of when editing files (without nay risk of breaking any conf

One last suggestion
I used 
sed -i 's/enabled=0/enabled=1/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
to change enabled =0 to enabled=1 under the [remi] section in remi.repo .However i have a feeling that it may modify all enabled=0 in that file , which will wreak the server.Can anyone suggest a better code.

---

Another stuff i am not sure of:P
I want to edit a file that has this as Text 
Testing = "0"(Yes it has quotes and i need to keep it) 
It should be modified from 
Testing = "0" to Testing = "1"(with quotes)

Also i need to add some text with quotes at the end of a file with sed
Like "Thanks Quanta"(with quote)
For php you put a \ with echoing quotes , don't know how it is done for bash

Another thing
I need to modify a line in a conf but i don't remember what is the whole of text to replaced

Like its listen = something; , i want to modify it to listen = /tmp/php5-fpm.sock;

Big thumbs up for up quanta

Thanks for the awesome support guys

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sed '/enabled=1/a\priority=10' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Specify an in-place editing option (`-i`) if you want (makes the backup with `.bak` extension first):

```
sed -i.bak '/enabled=1/a\priority=10' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

---

> Now i want use sed to do the following 1.Find the FIRST occurrence of
>   worker_processes in that conf and replace text with worker_processes
>   4;

```
sed '0,/worker_processes [0-9]*;/s//worker_processes 4;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

---

> One last suggestion I used  `sed -i 's/enabled=0/enabled=1/g'
>   /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` to change `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` under the
>   `[remi]` section in `remi.repo`. However i have a feeling that it may
>   modify all `enabled=0` in that file , which will wreak the server.Can
>   anyone suggest a better code

Here for you:

```
sed '/\[remi\]/,/enabled=0/ { s/enabled=0/enabled=1/ }' remi.repo
```

---

> Another stuff i am not sure of:P I want to edit a file that has this
>   as Text Testing = "0"(Yes it has quotes and i need to keep it) It
>   should be modified from Testing = "0" to Testing = "1"(with quotes)

```
sed 's/Testing = "0"/Testing = "1"/g'
```

> Also i need to add some text with quotes at the end of a file with sed
>   Like "Thanks Quanta"(with quote) For php you put a \ with echoing
>   quotes , don't know how it is done for bash

```
sed '$a"Werulz, you are welcome"\'
```

> Another thing I need to modify a line in a conf but i don't remember
>   what is the whole of text to replaced
>
> Like its listen = something; , i want to modify it to listen =
>   /tmp/php5-fpm.sock;

```
sed 's/listen = .*/listen = \/tmp\/php5-fpm.sock;/'
```

Comment: 'sed '/enabled=1/a\priority=10' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo' will edit the file and save the changes.PLease confirm

Comment: @Werulz: Just check with a file that doesn't matter or copy the contents of epel.repo to a file in the home directory and try running it there without root/superuser privileges.

Comment: `-i` is not a [standard option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html) for `sed`. [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/ed.html), however, offers a standards-compliant way to edit files with syntax very similar to sed's.

Comment: I updated my first post to ask you another suggestion.Thanks so much for support so far quanta.

Comment: I updated post again......sorry for asking so many questions . Will share script with you in case u need

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/60807668/SED-and-AWK-101-Hacks

Comment: To substitute just the first occurrence on MacOS: sed -i.bak 's/enabled: false/enabled: true/' sample.txt

Answer (score 12):

Like ptman said, [Augeas](http://augeas.net) can save you from using `sed`/`awk`:

```
$ augtool -s set /files/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo/epel/priority 10
```

will set the priority of the `epel` repository to 10. If the `priority` key already exists, it will set its value, otherwise it will add a `priority` entry after the last entry in the section.

The same goes for other values you may want to modify.

If you want to modify several values, you can even use `augtool` as an interpreter:

```
$ cat epel.augtool
#!/usr/bin/augtool -sf

# Make a variable
defvar epel /files/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo/epel

# Set values
set $epel/enable 1
set $epel/priority 10
set $epel/Testing 0
$ chmod +x epel.augtool
$ ./epel.augtool
Saved 1 file(s)
```

If you want to keep it in your bash script, you can pipe the commands into `augtool`:

```
cat <<EOF | augtool
# Make a variable
defvar epel /files/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo/epel

# Set values
set $epel/enable 1
set $epel/priority 10
set $epel/Testing 0
save
EOF
```

See `man augtool` for more options.

There are several avantages to using Augeas vs `sed`/`awk`:

- Augeas has parsers that know about the file syntax (in this case, `yum.repo` syntax). You won't take the risk of breaking the file syntax if your regex are wrong;
- the Augeas yum.repo parser knows about `yum.repo` sections, so you know that you're editing the right section;
- Augeas is idempotent. It will only make changes to the file if there are changes to be made. If all the values are already set, it won't modify the file;
- Augeas has a Puppet provider, so you can easily automate this in a Puppet infrastructure;
- if parameters don't exist yet, Augeas will create them for you. If the section doesn't exist yet, Augeas will also create it, with the proper syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the reply......will consider it for sure....Can u give an example of how to use it with my bash script

Comment: Ok, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out [Augeas](http://augeas.net/), tool for programmatically modifying config files. It is very powerful in combination with [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/) (a configuration management system), but can also be used by itself.

Comment: What is that lol

Comment: You can improve the quality of this answer by providing a brief description of what Augeas is/does, and also by adding an example or two.

Comment: I added a new question guys